# Can't use loc with DatetimeIndex

Tags: python, pandas

I can't select using loc when there is DatetimeIndex.

```
test = pd.DataFrame(data=np.array([[0, 0], [0, 2], [1, 3]), columns=pd.date_range(start='2019-01-01', end='2019-01-02', freq='D'))
test.loc[test>1, '2019-01-02']
```

I expect it to return pandas.Series([2, 3]), but it returns the error "Cannot index with multidimensional key"

Comment: The code to make the DataFrame doesn't even run.. you're passing 2 rows with 3 cols each, but only have 2 col names. Additionally, `test>1` isn't a correct comparison since `test` is a DataFrame, not a Series. This is the source of your problem, since `test>1` return a dataframe (a multidimensional key). What exactly are you trying to do? if you could update your question with working code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, your index is not a DatetimeIndex, only your columns are. The issue is that when you use `test>1` as a comparison, it will return a DataFrame with the same size as `test` with Booleans for each cell showing whether the value is > 1. When you pass an array of booleans, it expects it to be a 1 dimensional array, but since you're passing it a DataFrame (2 dimensional), you get the "multidemensional key" error. I believe what you want here is:

```
test.loc[test['2019-01-02']>1, '2019-01-02']
```